# Apache htaccess rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Am trying to update my site URL structure but facing issue with htaccess rewrite rules.

my old url is like this :
`http://www.example.com/index-test.php?page=5`

my goal is to rewrite it to something like this : `http://www.example.com/page/5`

so that when i visit `http://www.example.com/page/5` it forward that to index-test.php.

so for that i have wrote these two rules but its not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/?$  index-test.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^page/([^/d]+)/?$ index-test.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so any idea whats wrong with my htaccess rules.

Comment: why is the rule which *might work* commented out?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it not worked so i commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is :

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$  /index-test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You need to catch the page id after "/" with a set of (). Then in the rewrite, you have to use $1 (linked to the catched id).

Caution : This line will not work if you want access http://www.example.com/page/ without any id, if you want to, you can use :

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)*$  /index-test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: not working when i visit : www.example.com/page/3   it give 404 error :(

Comment: Humm, can you try with a / before :
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)*$  /index-test.php?page=$1 [L]

?

Comment: You're welcome, already got exactly the same problem in htaccess, a classic :p